# Why am i getting undefined jwt token value since token is stored in cookies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, cookies

The server services(localhost/8000) successfuly stored the jwt token in cookies and send response cookies to client services. The cookies successfully stored on client services(localhost/3000) but when i want to retrive it,it shows undefined.i also include the cookie-parser package but its still showing undefined.

server services:

```
export const saveprofile = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const profile = await new Profile(req.body);
        if (req.body.password === req.body.cpassword) {

            const token = await profile.generateAuthToken();
            res.cookie('token', token, { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 9999999), httpOnly: true })
            profile.save();
            res.status(200).json('profile saved !!');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        req.status(500).json(error);
    }
}
```

Now when i want to console the token stored in cookies through auth function,it shows undefined.

Auth function (middleware)

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import post from '../schema/post-schema.js'
import profile from '../schema/profile-schema.js';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';


const auth = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
       
        const token = req.cookies.jwt;
        console.log("The token is", token) //it shows undefined

        const verifyuser = jwt.verify(token, "mynameismohitkumarfromnationalinstituteoftechnologyagartala");
        const user = await profile.findOne({ _id: verifyuser._id });
        console.log(verifyuser);
        console.log(user);
        next();
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(401).json(error);
    }
}

export default auth;
```

Authentication Routes:

```
router.get('/post/:id', auth, getpost);
```

[image: cookie image]

[image: Network developer tool image]

Comment: Why are you using res.cookie and req.cookies.jwt? You seem to be using js-cookie, which means you should use Cookies.set and Cookies.get.

Comment: Have you tried console logging parent object? req.cookies or only req object maybe.

Comment: yes, i tried to console  req.cookies it is showing like [Object: null prototype] {}.

Comment: Actually in network ( developer tool ) it is showing status code as 401 Unauthorised on routing '/post/:id'.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue here is naming

You name the cookie `"token"` on the server-service and save it as such. But then in the auth-middleware you try to receive the `"jwt"`-cookie

As a side note:

`profile saved !!` is not valid JSON

Comment: Yes, that's a typo error. I make it correct but still showing the undefined. Actually in network ( developer tool ) it is showing status code as 401 Unauthorised